# Fortran and C interoperability: receive return value from c (calling from Fortran)

Tags: c, fortran

I have read a lot of posts on a similar topic but I have not yet succeeded resolving this. 
I should mention that I have simplified my code a lot for this post. 
My intention is to use a c function by calling it from fortran77 and receiving back values from c. The fact that I mention fortran77 is because I want to link my code to a much larger project that uses fortran77, but I am willing to consider solutions with other versions of fortran if they do the job and if you believe they will simplify my problem.

I have two files: Try_stack.f and client2.c.
I am compiling my code as:

```
gcc -c client2.c
gfortran -g Try_stack.f client2.o -o combined
```

My Try_stack.f file:

```
      program circle

      call circle2
      stop
      end

      subroutine circle2 
      dimension rread(2)
      double precision r, area,rread
      external client

      area = 3.
      rread(1)=area
      rread(2)=area+10.
      write (*,*) 'Area = ',  rread(1)
      call client(rread)
      retNread = rread(1) * 2
      write(*,*) 'new nread is: ',retNread

      return
      end
```

And my client2.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdint.h>

int client_(double rread[2]) 
{ 
    double result;
    result=1.;
    rread[1]=result;
    printf("%.2lf",rread);
    return 0; 
}
```

After running the compiled version I am getting:

Area =    3.0000000000000000
0.00 new nread is:    6.00000000

But, I wanted the return value to the fortran program to have been equal to 8.000 instead of 6.0000 (because fortran sends the value 3., 1. is added to 3. and a 4.0 should return back to fortran for multiplying it with 2.). If I wanted to write this in a simple way to explain it, I would say:

- First, I want the fortran file to send number 3. to c (actually I want to exchange arrays).
- Second, I want the c file to take number 3. and add 1.
- Third, I want c to return back the result to the fortran file, i.e. number 4.
- Finally, I want fortran to continue computing, in this case multiply 4*2=8.

I read a lot about iso_c_binding but I have not obviously managed to utilise it, plus it requires recent versions of Fortran if my understanding is correct.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should really reflect on 2019 -1977= 42.  Interoperability between Fortran and C is trivial using the features provided in modern Fortran.  BTW, Fortran indexing starts at 1.  C indexing starts at 2.  What happens if you `print *, rread(1), rread(2)` in your Fortran code?

Comment: Whoops.  C indexing starts at 0!  Collapsed want I meant to write.  The C declaration `double rread[2]` is 2 element with indexing starting at 0.

Comment: @evets: You are right. It was an indexing issue despite that I was already aware of the differences between the two languages. Thank you for the quick response. And a more elegant solution to modern fortran would be welcomed by me, although I can only read the old one for now.

Comment: Your Fortran code `call`s `client`, which must therefore correspond to the conventions for a Fortran subroutine (not function).  Typically, and I'm pretty sure gfortran is typical here, a Fortran subroutine corresponds to a C function having return type `void`.  I guess that wasn't your primary problem, but you should still fix it, rather than risking subtle problems arising.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Do you mean I should change the "int client_(double rread[2])" above to "void client_(double rread[2])"?

Comment: Yes, @Spartan, that's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Thank you John, but in this case I am getting the following warning which I guess I can ignore (my knowledge of c is almost 0, and that sample code above is part of a larger code): client2.c:14:5: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]
     return 0;

Comment: Well yes, @Spartan.  Use a `return` statement with no value (just `return;`), or else no `return` at all in a function declared to return `void`. This is really the point.  Fortran does not *expect* or use a return value, because you're calling the thing *as a subroutine*.  So it should not return anything, and it should be declared to not return anything.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: thank you so much John. I have learnt a lot here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of comments, did anyone actually compile and try to run this code?
Beside the FORTRAN (index start form 1) and C (index start from 0), there is a typo preventing you get expected result.

BTW, please use implicit none in any FORTRAN!

```
int client_(double rread[2]) 
{ 
    double result;
    result=1.;
    //rread[1]=result; --> typo?
    rread[0]+=result;
    printf("%.2lf",rread);
    return 0; 
}
```

Area =    3.0000000000000000
0.00 new nread is:    8.0000000000000000